# MySQL/PHP - page number pagination Only show 10 pages at times

Tags: php, mysql

I am having difficulties with my MYSQL / PHP dashboard. - Currently i am having 50 pages, but currently they are all showing on the same page.

[http://imgur.com/wDfTWUa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj85q.png) - as you can see in the attached file. - I only want 10 pages to be shown, and be able to click through the rest of the pages without seeing 4 rows of pages.

Exsampel <- 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ->  when you are on ?page=1, if you are on page ?page=10 <- 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19->

Hope you can help me.

Code:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$sidenr = $_GET['page'];

$sidenr2 = ($sidenr -1) * 10;

echo $sidenr2;
echo "<br><br>";

$query100 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `test` LIMIT $sidenr2,10") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query100))        
    {
        echo $row['id']."<br>";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM test");
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $sideantal = $num_rows / 10;

    echo "Der skal være antal sider: ". $sideantal;

    echo "<br><br>antal rækker ". $num_rows . "<br><br>";

    ?>
    <br><br>
    <?php

    for ($number = 1; $number <= $sideantal; $number++) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"test.php?page=".$number."\" >". $number. "</a></li>";
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
function getPageRange($current, $max, $total_pages = 10) {
    $desired_pages = $max < $total_pages ? $max : $total_pages;
    $middle = ceil($desired_pages/2);
    if ($current <= $middle){
        return [1, $desired_pages];
    }
    if ($current > $middle && $current <= ($max - $middle)) {
        return [
            $current - $middle,
            $current + $middle
        ];
    }
    if ($current <= $max ) {
        return [
            $current - ($desired_pages - 1),
            $max
        ];
    }

}
list($min,$max) = getPageRange($sidenr, $sideantal);


foreach (range($min, $max) as $number) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"test.php?page=".$number."\" >". $number. "</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: Hi, it works really well!
Only a problem, if there are only 2 pages, it should not count further up to 5 pages

Comment: Thank you it's 100% perfect now!

Answer (score 1):

try to change this:

```
for ($number = 1; $number <= $sideantal; $number++) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"test.php?page=".$number."\" >". $number. "</a>
    </li>";
}
```

to this:

```
for ($number = 1; $number <= $sideantal; $number++) {
    if (($number > $_GET['page']) && ($number <= $_GET['page'] + 10)) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"test.php?page=".$number."\" >". $number. "</a>
        </li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

It's really good! But when you go forward, but when you go back, do not take the fields so that is, when you reach the end of the pages, the links disappear. hope you understand

Comment: Exsample is if there only are 2 pages. and you are on page 2 its only show <- -> now.There it should show <- 1 ->

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
for ($number = 1; $number <= $sideantal; $number++) {
    /** If the loop count is greater than the current page but less than current page plus 10 */
    if ( ($number > $_GET['page'] && ($number < ($_GET['page'] + 10)))) $is_valid = true;


    /** If the loop count is less than the current page but greater than current page -10 and the current page is the last page */

    if ($number < $_GET['page'] && $_GET['page'] == $sideantal && $number > ($_GET['page'] - 10)) $is_valid = true;

    else $is_valid = false;

    if ($is_valid)  {
        echo "<li><a href=\"test.php?page=".$number."\" >". $number. "</a></li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: the webpage is completely blank with this script. sorry.