# Pagination - Limit the visible page numbers

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

I have about `10 000` products, where I am showing `10` products per page, resulting in `1000` pages.

Owing to this reason, I would like a limit of number of pages shown as in the pagination sample below:

```
Previous | 1 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 | ... | 1000 | Next
```

The pagination itself works perfect. It is only the shown page limit that is an issue.

Here is the code;

**DATABASE:**

```
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

/* CONFIGURE PAGINATION */

/*
Set default page value to 0
*/

$current_page = 0;

/*
If $_GET['start'] exists, is a valid integer and is positive set $current_page to this value
*/

if (isset($_GET['start']) && is_int($_GET['start']) && $_GET['start'] >= 0) {
    $current_page = $_GET['start'];
    $current_page = $current_page * $max_rows;
}

/*
Set $max_rows to the number of records you want to show on each page
*/

$max_rows = 10;

/*
Set default values for pagination variables
*/

$total_rows = 0;
$total_pages = 1;
$prev_page = 0;
$next_page = 0;
$page_from = 1;
$page_to = 0;

// query to get messages from messages table
$connOne = "SELECT product_name, product_quantity, product_id, product_price_lowest, product_price_highest FROM product ORDER BY product_price_lowest ASC, product_price_highest DESC LIMIT $current_page,      

$max_rows";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($connOne);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

/*
Your original row count query
*/

$count_query = "SELECT product_name, product_quantity, product_id, product_price_lowest, product_price_highest FROM product";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($count_query);
$stmt->execute();

$total_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

/*
Set $total_pages to ceiling of row count / max rows
*/

$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $max_rows);

/*
If $current_page is higher than total pages, reset to $total_pages
*/

if ($current_page > $total_pages) $current_page = $total_pages;

/*
Set variables to control which page numbers are shown
*/

$page_to = $total_pages;
   if ($current_page > 1) $prev_page = $current_page - 1;
   if ($total_pages > $current_page) $next_page = $current_page + 1;
   if ($total_pages > 5) {
   if (($current_page - 3) > 1) $page_from = $current_page - 3;
   if (($current_page + 3) < $total_pages) $page_to = $current_page + 3;
}
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

**PAGE OUTPUT:**

```
<?php
/* OUTPUT TO PAGE */

/*
Check that we've actually got some records, although I assume you're
doing this elsewhere
*/

if ($total_rows > 0) {
echo '<ul>';

/*
If we're not on the first page show a link to page 1 and an ellipsis
*/

if ($prev_page > 0) {
echo '<li><a href="?page=' . $prev_page . '">Previous</a></li>';
}
if ($page_from != 0) {
echo '<li><a href="?page=0">First</a></li>';
echo '<li><span>. . . </span></li>';
}

/*
Loop through the page numbers that we're showing and set class="active" on the current page
*/

for ($p = $page_from; $p <= $page_to; $p++) {
echo '<li' . ($current_page == $p ? ' class="active"' : '') . '> <a href=?page=' . $p . '>' . $p .  '</a> </li>';
}

/*
If we're not on the last page show an ellipsis and a link to the last page
*/

if ($page_to != $total_pages) {
echo '<li><span> . . . </span></li>';
echo '<li><a href="?page=' . $total_pages . '">' . $total_pages . '</a></li>';
}

if ($next_page > 0) {
echo '<li><a href="?page=' . $next_page . '">Next</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';

} else {
echo 'No records.';
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question a little better?

Comment: Sure. Well as I said, I have about 1000 pages and the links to all pages are all visible. Instead of showing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 etc.. up onto 1000. I would like to show like 5 page links with a "Previous" and "Next" button. Like this for example:  " PREVIOUS - 1... 11,12,13,14,15 .... 1000 - NEXT ".

Comment: Before helping you write some code, here's a few pointers and see how much you can figure out yourself first.

 Build a separate function that takes in the current page number, then returns a  range of next 5 pages and then the max. The previous and next button should just be whatever the current page number is + or  - 1 obviously. The idea is that as each new page is loaded, it calls the function to get the next range.

Comment: I think this is similar with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44997852/mysql-php-page-number-pagination-only-show-10-pages-at-times/45026442#45026442. It just need to add the previous and next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got a bit confused with a couple of bits. Try this - I've edited the code in your updated post. Before you edit the code to tweak things, see what result you get with what I've posted here.

I've replaced `$_GET['start']` with `$_GET['page']`. `$_GET['page']` is now the page number and *not* the start row.

**DATABASE:**

```
<?php


try {

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



/*
Set default page value to 1
*/

$current_page = 1;

/*
If $_GET['start'] exists, is a valid integer and is positive set $current_page to this value
*/

if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_int($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] >= 0) {
    $current_page = $_GET['page'];
}

/*
Set $max_rows to the number of records you want to show on each page
*/

$max_rows = 10;


/*
Set default values for pagination variables - don't change this
*/
$total_rows = 0;
$total_pages = 1;
$prev_page = 0;
$next_page = 0;
$page_from = 1;
$page_to = 0;

/*
Your original row count query
*/

$count_query = "SELECT product_name, product_quantity, product_id, product_price_lowest, product_price_highest FROM product";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($count_query);
$stmt->execute();

$total_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

/*
Set $total_pages to ceiling of row count / max rows
*/

$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $max_rows);

/*
If $current_page is higher than total pages, reset to $total_pages
*/
if ($current_page > $total_pages) $current_page = $total_pages;


/*
Set start row for DB query
*/
$db_start_row = ($current_page * $max_rows) - $max_rows;

// query to get messages from messages table
$connOne = "SELECT product_name, product_quantity, product_id, product_price_lowest, product_price_highest FROM product ORDER BY product_price_lowest ASC, product_price_highest DESC LIMIT $db_start_row, $max_rows";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($connOne);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

/*
Set variables to control which page numbers are shown
*/

$page_to = $total_pages;
   if ($current_page > 1) $prev_page = $current_page - 1;
   if ($total_pages > $current_page) $next_page = $current_page + 1;
   if ($total_pages > 5) {
   if (($current_page - 2) > 1) $page_from = $current_page - 2;
   if (($current_page + 2) < $total_pages) $page_to = $current_page + 2;
}
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

**PAGE OUTPUT:**

```
<?php


/*
 * Check that we've actually got some records, although
 * I assume you're doing this elsewhere
 */
if ( $total_rows > 0 ) {

    echo '<ul>';

    /*
     * If we're not on the first page show a link to page 1 and an ellipsis 
     */
    if ( $prev_page > 0 ) {
        echo '<li><a href="?page=' . $prev_page . '">Previous</a></li>';
    }
    if ( $page_from != 1 ) {
        echo '<li><a href="?page=1">1</a></li>';
        echo '<li><span>...</span></li>';
    }

    /*
     * Loop through the page numbers that we're showing and set class="active"
     * on the current page
     */
    for ( $p = $page_from; $p <= $page_to; $p++ ) {
        echo '<li' . ( $current_page == $p ? ' class="active"' : '' ) . '><a href=?page=' . $p . '>' . $p . '</a></li>';
    }

    /*
     * If we're not on the last page show an ellipsis and a link to the last page
     */
    if ( $page_to != $total_pages ) {
        echo '<li><span>...</span></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="?page=' . $total_pages . '">' . $total_pages . '</a></li>';
    }
    if ( $next_page > 0 ) {
        echo '<li><a href="?page=' . $next_page . '">Next</a></li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';

} else {
    echo 'No records.';
}

?>
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it does limit the amount of pages. But now the links do not work anymore. For example if i press NEXT or a specific page number the table remains the same.  The only time the table changes information is when I manually, in the code, change " $current_page = 0; " to another value. It is as if 0 is static and it does not take into account the adding of +1 in: "if ($total_pages > $current_page) $next_page = $current_page + 1; ". PLEASE NOTE, I updated the code in my first post as well so you can see how it looks now.

Comment: Is `$_GET['start']` the page number or the start row? So, if I'm on page 4 will `$_GET['start']` = 4 or 30?

Comment: You added a line that changed `$current_page` and this screwed the rest of the pagination up. I've edited my answer to include your extra db stuff and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I just tried your new code and still have the same issue. The table remains the same regardless of what link i click on, that is, the same 10 rows with products is the same. If i click on 1, then the URL changes to page 1, same output when i click on 2 and 3 (but the table with 10 rows of data is always the same). When I am on 3 and click on NEXT, then the URL goes to "page 2". Also, a previous button never pops up when clicking on 2 or 3. I tried to manually change   $current_page = 1 to   $current_page = 14; and only then did the table actually update on the website.

Comment: I am going out on a limb here, but do you think here is where the problem is?   /*
  If $_GET['start'] exists, is a valid integer and is positive set $current_page to this value
  */

  if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_int($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] >= 0) {
      $current_page = $_GET['page'];
  }

Comment: I changed   $current_page = 1; to $current_page = $_GET['page']; and it works!! The 1,2,3 etc buttons work. The NEXT button works. I even got a PREVIOUS button as well. The only problem now is the default. When the URL is http://localhost/test2.php? I get an error. I have to manually change the URL to http://localhost/test2.php?page=1 and go on from there, and then it works.

Comment: I don't really understand why this makes a difference. $current_page is set to 1 by default. If $_GET['page'] is a valid value (positive integer) then it sets $current_page to this anyway. It's just a tiny bit of simple validation that's now been removed. But hey, if it's working then it's working :)